# Swap column header icons and change the state of the filter icon after filter selection in ag-grid-aurelia

Tags: ag-grid

I am new to ag-grid integration with Aurelia. I have used ag-grid Aurelia component. In ag-grid sort and filter functionality implemented and is working fine.

While using sorting and filtering, I want to swap the Icons those are getting displayed on column header.

In header sort ascending / descending icon should come after filter icon, also I want to change the icon colors.

[image: refernce]

For customizing the ag-grid column header I am following below links:

1. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-header/#example-header-template 
   and customizing header component
2. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#gsc.tab=0

available in the ag-grid documentation support in the link provided above.

Can anybody tell me how to do this in quick way. Is there any property available in ag-agrid. I am using 13.3 version of ag-grid.

Comment: please read [ask], share your code with us and where you have a problem